Find next element which is greater than or equal to two times the element for every element in the array
Description of the Algorithm:
For each element of the input array, find the next element which is greater than or equal to two times the element.
In other words, for i, j where j>i
output[i]=input[j], if and only if, input[j]>=2*input[i]
Example:
idx:     0   1   2   3   4   5   6
Input:  23, 35, 12, 47, 33, 68, 34
Output: 47, -1, 47, -1, 68, -1, -1

Explanation:
For idx=3, there is no element greater than or equal to two times of 47 i.e. >=94
For idx=4, 68(idx=5) is greater than 47

Can anyone suggest me an algorithm which has better time complexity than O(n^2)?

Here's a solution which is O(n log n) using a min heap (implemented via the heapq library in python) of tuples of (value, index). It works by iterating the array, comparing the current value with the smallest value in the heap and seeing if it is twice as large. While it is, the corresponding index in the output is set to this value. The current value is then pushed into the heap.
from heapq import heappop, heappush

def two_x(arr):
    heap = []
    out = [-1] * len(arr)
    for i, v in enumerate(arr):
        while heap and v >= 2 * heap[0][0]:
            out[heappop(heap)[1]] = v
        heappush(heap, (v, i))
    return out

two_x([23, 35, 12, 47, 33, 68, 34])

Output:
[47, -1, 47, -1, 68, -1, -1]


I'm motivated by your short and tidy answer to read up on min heaps.

It does make for a very uncomplicated solution for this particular problem. There's another cool use here

The len call is unnecessary; while heap suffices.

You can iterate in reverse while maintaining a monotonic stack. To get each output, binary search in the elements of the stack for the closest element that is at least two times the current element. This results in a total time complexity of O(n log n).
Sample implementation in Java:
public static int[] solve(int[] input) {
    int[] output = new int[input.length], stk = new int[input.length];
    int top = -1;
    for (int i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int low = 0, high = top;
        while (low <= high) {
            int mid = low + high >>> 1;
            if (stk[mid] < 2 * input[i]) high = mid - 1;
            else low = mid + 1;
        }
        output[i] = high < 0 ? -1 : stk[high];
        while (top >= 0 && input[i] >= stk[top]) --top;
        stk[++top] = input[i];
    }
    return output;
}


Another O(nlog(n)) solution is to step through the array whilst maintaining at array of indices of past elements that are still awaiting their two-times soulmate.
The solution is in Ruby.
Helper method
First a helper method that will insert n into the array unmatched, keeping the array sorted.
def insert_in_unmatched(unmatched, n)
  i = unmatched.bsearch_index { |m| m > n }
  unmatched.insert(i, n)
end

The methods Array#bsearch_index and Array#insert are both written in C so they should be reasonable efficient.
For example,
unmatched = [1, 2, 2, 5, 7, Float::INFINITY]
insert_in_unmatched(unmatched, 3)
unmatched
  #=> [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, Infinity]

unmatched = [1, 2, 2, 5, 7, Float::INFINITY]
insert_in_unmatched(unmatched, 0)
unmatched
  #=> [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, Infinity]

unmatched = [1, 2, 2, 5, 7, Float::INFINITY]
insert_in_unmatched(unmatched, 8)
unmatched
  #=> [1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 8, Infinity]

Main method
The main method follows.
def doit(arr)
  output = Array.new(arr.size)
  unmatched = [Float::INFINITY]
  unmatched_to_index = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
  arr.each_with_index do |n,i|
    loop do
      break if unmatched.empty?
      m = unmatched.first
      break if 2*m > n
      unmatched_to_index[m].each { |k| output[k] = n }
      unmatched_to_index.delete(m)
      unmatched.shift
    end
    insert_in_unmatched(unmatched, n)
    unmatched_to_index[n] << i     
  end
  output
end

Notes

output = Array.new(arr.size) uses the method Array::new to create an array having as many elements as the array arr, those elements initially equal to nil.

unmatched_to_index = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] } employs one form of the method Hash::new to create a hash having the property that if h does not have a key k, h[k] first sets the value of k equal to an empty array. For example, if
h = { 2=>[0], 4=>[2,3] }


then h[3] << 1 results in
h #=> { 2=>[0], 4=>[2,3], 3=>[1] }

The value of 3 is initially set to an empty array, [] then << 1 appends 1 to that array.
If this were followed by h[3] << 4 4 would simply be appended to the existing array [1]:
h #=> { 2=>[0], 4=>[2,3], 3=>[1,4] }


When element n at index i of arr is being considered, unmatched is a sorted array of elements arr[j], j < i that have not as yet been matched with the first element arr[k], k > j for which 2*arr[j] <= arr[k].

break if unmatched.empty? simply breaks out of the otherwise never-ending loop loop if unmatched is empty.

For each k of the array unmatched_to_index[m], arr[k] #=> m.

unmatched_to_index[m].each { |k| output[k] = n } assigns arr[i] #=> n as the first element in arr for which 2*m <= n, where m is the value of all elements k in unmatched_to_index[m] for which arr[k] #=> m and k < i.

unmatched.shift removes the first element of unmatched.


